# How to compare two kafka tables?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Kafka Stream Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaStreams
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {


  @Bean(name = KafkaStreamsDefaultConfiguration.DEFAULT_STREAMS_CONFIG_BEAN_NAME)
  KafkaStreamsConfiguration kstreamConfig(){
    Map<String,Object> props=new HashMap<>();
    props.put(APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG,"MY_GROUP_ID");
    props.put(BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    props.put(DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    props.put(DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    return new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
  }
}
```

//My logic

```
    KTable<String,String> table1=streamsBuilder.table("TOPIC1");
    KTable<String,String> table2=streamsBuilder.table("TOPIC2");
```

Now I've two tables, I need to compare these two tables and the data which are not present in the table1 will be send to another kafka topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [`StreamsBuilderFactoryBean#getKafkaStreams()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.html#getKafkaStreams()) to get a `KafkaStreams` instance.

Then call [`streams.store(StoreQueryParameters.fromNameAndType("<store-name>", QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()))`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html#store(org.apache.kafka.streams.StoreQueryParameters)) to get both stores, which you can iterate and compare using [`all()`](https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/ReadOnlyKeyValueStore.html)

For any differences you want to send to another topic, use `KafkaTemplate` producer